# Making Scroll Effect Smoother (Mobile)

Tags: javascript, jquery, mobile, gsap

I have a web design portfolio that I'm working on, and I'm using the Green Sock Animation Platform to fade out navigation elements that are fixed on the top of page, that ultimately becomes invasive in nature while scrolling (which is why I fade it out on scroll past the marketing splash.)

GSAP does an excellent job of fading it out, but the issue is when a user slides down it's extremely touchy-feely in regards to triggering the Tweens.

Is there a method or trick that anybody knows of that makes it so even if a user doesn't take their finger off the screen while in the process of scrolling it still triggers the Tweens?

Here's the code below, and you can see it in action @ http://drootech.com

```
$(window).scroll(function() {
    var nav = document.getElementById("navi");
    if ($(this).scrollTop() * 0.0623 > 25){
        TweenLite.to(nav, 1.5, {css:{autoAlpha:0}});
    } else if ($(this).scrollTop() * 0.0623 < 25){
        TweenLite.to(nav, 2, {css:{autoAlpha:1}});
    }
});
```

Comment: One problem you're likely facing is that mobile browsers don't tend to fire the scroll event nearly as often as their desktop versions. Also, fading opacity on mobile can be cpu intensive which can cause other transitions/functionality to behave less smoothly.

Comment: @ArrayKnight I could see that. 

Is there anyway to force the mobile browser to fire the scroll event rapidly, or at least comparably to the desktop, without compromising performance?

The GSAP animation is perfect, it's not clunky and slow like jQuery animation. So that's not my concern, it's more along the lines of improving the rate of firing the scroll event.

Comment: @AndrewSquire You don't want to fire the scroll event continously on mobile - trust me on that. You'll kill performance completely. I would suggest reworking your nav a bit. Since it's fixed in the top I would drop the opacity animation completely. Either have the nav visible all the time for quick navigation, or let it scroll out of view along with the content.

Comment: You could do a semi hack by detecting swipe directions (Fx using TouchSwipe, https://github.com/mattbryson/TouchSwipe-Jquery-Plugin) and then trigger the animation.

Comment: Not that anyone cares.

But since this was mainly an iOS related problem, I just decided to go with it. It's not that bad, just mainly after seeing the famo.us framework in action I wanted to accomplish comparable performance via GSAP.

The whole point is to hide the element, and it still fades out right for unique visitors who tend to pause at the perfect spot to read the marketing :)

Thanks for the suggestions though @cowcowmoomoo